# If I buy Angry Birds on iPad and iPhone, do I have to buy it again on the Mac App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I just wanted to be able to play on a bigger screen... but have already paid $4.99 for Angry Bird on iPad.  It is the exact same game (same content) on the Mac... do I have to pay again actually?  (if the answer is yes or no, can you quote some source for reference?)  thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a source, but the thing is that the iPad/iPhone AppStore is *different* than the Mac Apple Store. The iPhone game costs 0.99, whereas the iPad version (optimized for the larger screen) is more expensive, yet these two apps are in the same Store.

Since there's no way (thanks the Apple) to provide free upgrades to the Mac Apple Store for existing customers, Rovio charges you for the game again if you want it in your Mac, no matter how easy it was to port for them.

It was probably not a super hard task, but in terms of administrative work, they have no choice unless they'd wanted to give it away for free, which clearly they aren't.

So the answer is yes, you have to buy it again from the Mac Apple Store.

Comment: yeah... if I want to play it at home (using a PC), then will need to buy again for $4.99 using Intel App Up... so... $4.99 x 3 = $15 for iPad, Mac, PC, for the same game...

Comment: it is Rovio, btw... for the record

Comment: In Rovio's (and Apple's) defence, OS X is a different *platform* from iOS, and they had to make substantial modifications to the game to port it over. I'd hardly begrudge them another five bucks for their effort. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they're different products, so they are purchased separately. Just as Angry Birds HD (iPad) is a separate product from Angry Birds (iPhone/iPod touch), the Mac version is a *different application*.